# How to formal paragraph text via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, formatting

I'm trying to create a syntax highlighter that reviews code and adds bolding to certain keywords.  I attempted to replace a given keyword with `<b> keyword </b>`, but the `<b>` tags were actually visible in the paragraph.  How can I actually format the text?  This is my code.

```
var textbox = $("#textbox")
var code = $("#code")

var patterns = {
    "<b> </b>": ["local", "function"]
}

function format(text) {
    for (var pattern in patterns) {
        for (var keyword in pattern) {
            text = text.replace(patterns[pattern][keyword], pattern.replace(" ", patterns[pattern][keyword]))
        }
    }
    return text
}

textbox.change(function() {
    code.text(format(textbox.val()))
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are using `text()` method which will treat any html entities as text also.

Use `html()` instead since you are including html tags

```
textbox.change(function() {
    code.html(format(textbox.val()))
})
```